# React Native Performance issue with array sorting

Tags: react-native

I'm in the process of checking if React-Native is capable of handling a point in my native application that based on it I will take the decision whither or not to migrate my app to React Native.

Here is the scenario that I'm testing. The app is connecting to a server using socket.io. Then I'm requesting the full product list (350 product). Once I receive the list I sort it ascending according to their price using native code (Objective C for iOS and Java for Android). Then I show the result.

Then The app just keep listing to the server updates. The server send me update about 60 products every 10ms. Every time I should be able to sort them and and render them.

Now this was terrible performance wise. CPU is always between 160% and 200%. Rendering is extremely slow.

First approach I took was to look for a React-Native module that make the same concept as recycle view in Android and collection view in iOS. I was able to find one (recyclerlistview) (https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview). Unfortunately it didn't effect much on the rendering. Then I decide to limit the view to 17 product only. Which made significant improvement on the rendering (steady 60FPS).

But that made the rendering extremely fast for the human eye to keep track of the changes. So I made a small change, I used the forceUpdate function inside an interval that runs every 1 second which made it readable.

But I'm still unable to find a solution to my CPU huge usage. I even changed it from normal built it sorting to use a merge sort algorithm. But still I'm unable to lower the usage at all.

Any work around this kind of performance issue.

**Extra info**

1. setState is only run once at the start of the app. So there is no rendering being made except through the forceUpdate function.
2. React: 16.3.1
3. React-Native: 0.55.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the array using merge sort algorithm in native code (objective c in iOS, Java in Android) then render the screen through the forceUpdate function using an interval (ex: 1second). This way the CPU won't exceed the 80% mark and the energy impact will be medium. Since this is the only intensive screen in the mobile application then there is no need to do anything else.

P.S 
remember once you get out of this screen or navigate to another screen to send to the server request to stop sending updates.